# MySQL error #1064, an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to the MySQL

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to run a SQL query, using XAMPP, phpmyadmin and it returns this error:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'source tables/unit_type.sql' at line 1

I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find anything that works

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `unit_type`;

CREATE TABLE `unit_type`
(
    `unit_type_id` INTEGER NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `matcher_id` VARCHAR(32) NULL,
    `unit_type_name` VARCHAR(64) NOT NULL,
    `vendor_name` VARCHAR(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `description` VARCHAR(2000) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci NULL,
    `protocol`    VARCHAR(16) NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (`unit_type_id`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `uq_unit_type_name` (`unit_type_name`(64))
)
ENGINE = innodb CHARACTER SET = latin1 COLLATE = latin1_general_ci;
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The problem is not the code in the script. It is how you execute it. Look at the error message: Error at code line `source tables/unit_type.sql`

Comment: maybe your mysql version is too low.

Comment: This error message doesn't make sense with the code you posted. Are you running this from within phpMyAdmin? Using the SQL tab? Is the SQL you've posted what you paste directly in the SQL tab or is it contained in a file you're trying to import? If you're trying to import a file, use the Import tab instead. Is the SQL file on the server or on your local machine?

Comment: You appear to be trying to execute a script in the MySQL CLI, or PHP's query panel. Is that right?